# Another way to say...it "ends up" to be

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a better way to say the following:

It ends up that Nancy was the obtuse one.

Comment: You could just remove everything in front of *Nancy*. Unless you can provide guidance for what you don't like about *it ends up that* and for what type of word or phrase you want to replace it with, the question is too broad and subjective.

Comment: *It turns out that...* or *in the final wash* or *we discovered that...* or many many other options.... I agree with Jason that as currently worded, this question is **too broad**, so I'm flagging it as such.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend **ultimately**.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ultimately):

1 : in the end